# Full screen html 5 video styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have been working on creating a custom video for our client. This include color schemes and their logo on the controls bar.

I did all of this successfully using js and css.

Only problem is when I go full screen the player reverts back to the original html 5 player. Thankfully when I close fullscreen It goes back to my designed player.

Is there some sort of code I can use to enable me to style the fullscreen element?

Thanks in advance :)

```
<p>https://jsfiddle.net/1hfpt39m/</p>
<p>http://cpdonline.tv/ice-events/mediaplayer/</p>
```

I have uploaded a JS fiddle, although it doesnt seem to be functional and i dont know what. I have added the JS JQ and CSS as resources too.

I have also added a link the where the video player is currently live on a webpage.

Comment: post your demo code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Edit done :) Although the output doesnt seem to function. First time using fiddle.

Comment: Hey there, I searched a bit and found a post on css/tricks that can help. [Css-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/), there you have the link, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

rather than edit a fiddle or paste code, I'd rather redirect you to the page that details how to style your video player's play buttons, progress bar and other functions using CSS3, JS and HTML

Check out the detailed post [here](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/).

Also, find the demo styled video player [here](http://www.inserthtml.com/demo/html5-video/#).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its funny you posted this because this is where i got the source from to make the custom player in the first place. Unfortunately the demo player also does not have a custom fullscreen control bar

Comment: @BrendonWells - One possible solution could be to set the z-index of your controls to a very high number, say `z-index:9999999;` when triggering fullscreen play. Check it [here](https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/)

Comment: Unfortunately did not do anything :( Might be because i dont have it coded for any fullscreen stuff. I was hoping it would be an easy fix or a line of CSS that i can code under that would effect the fullscreen view.